# How to embed an XSLT file in a .NET project to be included in the output .exe?

Tags: c#, project, csproj

I have a simple C# Console App that reads in an XML file specified the the user, runs an XSLT transformation on it, and outputs the results.

When I distribute my app to users, I want to distribute a single .EXE file.  My source code consists of 3 files: the .csproj file, the .cs code file, and a .xslt stylesheet.

How can I set up the csproj so the .xslt is "embedded" within the output and cannot be seen or modified by the end user?

Seems easy, but I can't figure it out and Google isn't being too useful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can embedd it in your assembly.

Add the file in your solution, set the build action to embedded resource.

The place you need to read the file use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt.aspx Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream wich will give you a stream wich you can write to a fil or use directly.

If you are not quite sure what name your resource have, I find `Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames` usefull to list all resources.

Answer (score 31):

Add the file to your project, then select the file and go to the Properties window (press <kbd>F4</kbd>). Set the build action to "Embedded resource". This will cause the file to be embedded into the exe file as a resource.

```
using(Stream strm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("YourAssemblyName.filename.xslt"))
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strm))
{
    XslTransform transform = new XslTransform();
    transform.Load(reader);
    // use the XslTransform object
}
```

Comment: To augment Fredrik's example, you can use your application's namespace as the "YourAssemblyName", as in `...GetManifestResourceStream("This.is.my.namespace.filename.xslt"))`